# Should there be a level of indirection between db and routes in Clojure web app?

Tags: clojure, architecture

Let's say I'm doing a web app that exposes API to fetch and mutate data about cats.

I'm implementing my db layer using Korma, so there will be something like that:

```
(ns kittens.db
  (:require [korma.core :refer :all]))

(defn fetch-cats [db]
  (select cats-table ...))

(defn fetch-cat-by-id [db id]
  (select cats-table
          ...
          (where {:id id})))

(defn create-cat [db data]
  (insert cats-table
          ...))

...
...
```

After I'm implementing API routes as follows:

```
(ns kittens.routes
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET POST ...]]
            [kittens.db :as db]))

(defroutes cats-routes
  (GET "/cats" [...] (db/fetch-cats ...))
  (GET "/cats/:id" [...] (db/fetch-cat-by-id ...))
  (POST "/new-cat" [...] (db/create-cat ...)))
```

In such implementation `routes` module talks directly to `db` module, which seems kinda inflexible to me. Should there be something in between of them?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you do not need anything else, this is good.

Such a setup is already plenty flexible.

Seeing as all looks good, here is some general advice as things grow:

Avoid putting logic route bodies.
If the body of a route starts to grow, consider extracting it to a function.
Routes are less fun to test.

Colocate your routes and handler middleware unless you have so many routes they need to be split out into contexts.

Make sure your handler references the routes var #' not the routes directly so that reloading routes will work.